# How to get the minimum value of the same 1st 4 columns using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I need some help in getting the minimum value of the same first 4 columns while keeping the ones with no duplicates as well.

input file:

```
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010000
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010002
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010002
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010002
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010001
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010002
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010003
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010004
20180509,1086776,0004,Car2,0.010004
20200509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010005
20180509,0000006,0004,Car1,0.010005
20180509,1086776,0005,Car1,0.010005
```

output:

```
20180509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010000
20180509,1086776,0004,Car2,0.010004
20200509,1086776,0004,Car1,0.010005
20180509,0000006,0004,Car1,0.010005
20180509,1086776,0005,Car1,0.010005
```

last 4 lines of output file was kept since it has a unique combination of first four columns. anyone can help me with this?
an explanation would also help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: sort by last field and pick the unique keys, by definition it will give you the min for each unique key.

Comment: @Vinri Eclar - Are "the same first 4 columns" always consecutive? Is the output order required to be as shown?

Comment: I tried checking other codes for this but It only involves 1 column as 1 key and I'm not really good in disecting the codes. @Armali first 4 columns are not always consecutive. They may be in different order.  Output doesn't also require sorting in the end.

Answer (score 1):

so I was able to do this by using the following. I just found out how to place multiple columns of a key.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1 {rec=$0; m[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$5; next}
    {
        if (($1,$2,$3,$4) in m) {
            if ($5 < m[$1,$2,$3,$4]) {
                rec=$0
                m[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$5
            }
        }
        else {
            print rec
            rec=$0
            m[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$5
        }
    }
END {
    print rec
}' filename
```